# Android Google Login Button and Facebook sdk 4+ Button Layout

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, android-linearlayout, android-facebook

I Am developing an application which use [google](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button) and [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/) integration ...I want to fix height and width of those button...and i want to set Button Text Manualy...

i had tried so far

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
       xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:text="@string/fbloginText"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
/>

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/googleloginText" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

although i had attemted something like this

```
    fb:login_text="Login"
    fb:logout_text="Logout"

         or 

    facebook:login_text="Login"
```

But i Got Error::=>No resource identifier found for attribute 'login_text' in package 'com.test.b2c'

or in  by coding

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.connectWithFbButton);
     loginButton.setText("Login");
```

Now My layout Look Something Like This

[image]

I also want to set Height And width of this buttons .. ...
help me friends .....thx in advance

**UPDATE**

I have no direct problem in setting width what am I really concern is the inconsistent HEIGHT shown in the picture. I need to find better way(s) to make those buttons height equally nd set Text to those Button.

[image]

Comment: Help me friends i m Looking for your answer???

Comment: For width you have used match_parent just change it to either wrap_content or any size you want.

Comment: width dosent matter @Shvet ..look at picture both the botton have same width but what abt height i set it to 50dp but dosent work

Comment: Its not surprising that you'll get different outputs from a different library, The problem might be solve if you can find out the right namespace for adjusting width and height.

Comment: i had set this already 50 dp height why height is inconsistant

Comment: try adding android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" IF IT STILL NOT WORKING refer to the API docs.

Comment: thx @deadlydragon00 it solve height problem now turn to fb_login_text...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365713/android-google-login-button-and-facebook-sdk-4-button-layout/30370094#30370094

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we wanna change custom text of Facebook Login ..

Go to that Facebook library project And go to string.xml

you will find something like this

```
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Log in with facebook </string>
```

Replace this with your custom text

Although if you want to change custom text of Google Plus you can

From **OnCreate** call this

```
 setGooglePlusButtonText(signinButton,"your custom text");
```

//Text Change Method Of Google Plus

```
protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton,
    String buttonText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

       if (v instanceof TextView) {
           TextView tv = (TextView) v;
           tv.setTextSize(15);
           tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
           tv.setText(buttonText);
         return;
         }
      }
}
```

For Height inconsistancy of facebook i had add padding to **Facebook Button XML**

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

Comment: In case you have imported Facebook SDK via graddle (you can't modify sources), you can customize your text overriding the string in your strings.xml, declaring an item with this ID:   `<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Your custom text</string>`

Answer (score 11):

This xml code for style customizes my app's facebook login button like in the picture (in text and button size).

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Facebook"
    facebook:com_facebook_logout_text="Facebook" />
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: While the text size increases, the size of facebook logo does not. Is there a way to increase facebook icon size?

Answer (score 2):

Add linear layout and add these 2 button in it :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLinear" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
       xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"  
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:text="@string/fbloginText"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/googleloginText" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give Correct **Height**, **Width** and **Margin** for both  button

Comment: same result inconsistant height and width

Comment: Editted answer `android:height="wrap_content"`.. this will work pls check

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `android:layout_width` to either `wrap_content`, or a specific size, preferably in dp's (e.g. `20dp`, `30dp`, `40dp`).

As for the error, it is probably shown because you didn't edit your strings.xml, try using Android Studio, it will automatically create these values for you, and will also show you a preview of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the

```
android:layout_width="any size in dps"
android:layout_height="any size in dps"
```

and for setting the buttons manually you can concern with the specific docs. i,e [check it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) or 
this is a good [example](https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725).

Comment: width dosent matter @Junaid Hafeez..look at picture both the botton have same width but what abt height i set it to 50dp but dosent work

Comment: @Junaid check the comment above.

Comment: @Tufan your WIDTH is set to "match_parent", which means that it will use any space available, it will go from one edge of the screen to other. WIDTH = left-right, HEIGHT = up-down

Comment: @Aleksandar Stefanović look at both the pics ...check google login and facebook login button height ...i set it to 50dp but dosent work

Answer (score 0):

In your Facebook Widget add the following:

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
loginView:login_text="your custom text here"
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to include this:

```
xmlns:loginView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: loginView:login_text="your custom text here" this is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    fb:com_facebook_login_text="Your Text"
```