# Customizing Facebook login button in Android Application

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an android application in which I have implemented facebook login button.My login screen consists of some fields for sign up along with option of signing up with facebook and google+. Everything is working fine but I am unable to resize my button in terms of height. When I am changing my height of that button it doesn't change and remain in wrap content format, but width is changing. I am unable to find good solution to this problem on any of the previous questions . Can anyone please help me, if any additional detail is needed then please ask.
PS- I am using linear layout in my login screen.

Comment: check my ans it will help you

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365713/android-google-login-button-and-facebook-sdk-4-button-layout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365713/android-google-login-button-and-facebook-sdk-4-button-layout/30370094#30370094

Comment: It is working for text change of facebook.

Comment: But if you want to change the height properly then you need to make some changes in facebook sdk code.

Comment: It also holds true for increasing spacing from our text to image of facebook(symbol f) then also we need to make some changes in facebook sdk code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna change custom text of Facebook Login ..

Go to that facebook library project And go to string.xml

you will find something like this

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Log in with facebook </string>
```

Replace this with your custom text

For Height inconsistancy of facebook i had done something like this

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

Comment: I want to ask one omore question that i have chaneged strings.xml of facebook but my text didnot changed. can you tell me what can be the reason'

Comment: did you exactly change in this line because this line is changing text in my app <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Log in with facebook </string>

Comment: which sdk you are using this is working in facbook sdk4

Comment: I am using latest sdk v4.2

Comment: also ur google+ suggestion of changing text in other answer is also not working

Comment: dude that is working perfactly for me dnt know what u have problem..check this question is asked by me ..nd i m not satisfy with any answer so i had posted my ans..can you clearly tell me waht problem you have

Comment: thankyou for all of your help finally it worked, actually it is working on real device both facebook and googl+ thing nad i was just wondering that changes will occur on the graphical layout (I am very new to android), sorry for inconvenience caused.

Comment: its okay ..keep it up dude

Comment: if u think my question was worth asking then please upvote it will help me :)